# How to enter data manually in a cell and the date is automatique in adjacent cell and to change it, request password?

Tags: excel, vba

The code returns error messages implying some parts of code are missing yet they are there. E.g With without End With, and of course it's there.

These are two codes that i wrote separately with the aim of combining after making sure that they function well. But it turns out i need some help to get them together.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim k As Integer
Dim j As Integer

If Target.Column = 4 Then
confirm = MsgBox("Do you wish to confirm entry of this data?" _
& vbCrLf & "You'll not be allowed to change it!", vbYesNo, "confirm Entry")
Select Case confirm
Case Is = vbYes
Dim Cell As Range
With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:="10"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For j = 4 To 4
    For k = 10 To 60
    If Cells(k, j).Value <> "" Then
    Cells(k, "C").Value = Date
    Cells(k, "C").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Else
    Cell.Locked = True
    End If
   Next
    .Protect Password:="10"
    Case Is = vbNo
    Next
    Next
    Range("C11:C60").Columns.AutoFit

End With
End If
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm trying to get this code to automatically do the following :
When cell is empty then information can be entered then display date in adjecent cell after the data is in the cell. And when the data needs to be changed request for password with yes/no vba functions.

Comment: What happens when you switch `End If` and `End Select` with each other?

Comment: @Nacorid thanks for your response. I did just that but it's returning case without Select Case. And we can both see that it's there in the code...

Comment: The problem seems to be do to with `Case Is = vbNo` being inside the `With/End With` block. You might need to start the `With` block *before* the `Select` block. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code, though haven't tested if it does what you want it to do, it at least compiles:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim confirm As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        confirm = MsgBox("Do you wish to confirm entry of this data?" _
                & vbCrLf & "You'll not be allowed to change it!", vbYesNo, "confirm Entry")
        Select Case confirm
        Case vbYes
            With Me
                .Unprotect Password:="10"
                .Cells.Locked = False
                For k = 10 To 60
                    If .Cells(k, 4).Value <> "" Then
                        .Cells(k, 3).Value = Date
                        .Cells(k, 3).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
                    End If
                Next
                .Cells.Locked = True
                .Protect Password:="10"
                .Range("C11:C60").Columns.AutoFit
            End With
        End Select
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```